# How to get messages column up on the right?

Tags: html, css

HTML Section :

```
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='box'>
            Name:<br>
            <input type='text' id='name' size='10'><br><br>
            Message:<br>
            <textarea id='message' size='15' ></textarea><br><br>
            <br>
            <div id='Send'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Send</div>
        </div>
        <div class='messages'>
            <div id='loader'></div>
            <ul class='update'></ul>
            <?php //include(messages.php) ?>
        </div>


    </div>
```

CSS Section:

```
#box{
    width:300px;
    height: 230px;
    border:solid #6895CC 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #666;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #666;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:50px 0 0 400px;

}
#name{
    width:300px;
    height: auto;
    border:solid #6895CC 1px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:5px 5px 0 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#message{
    width:300px;
    height: auto;
    border:solid #6895CC 1px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:5px 5px 0 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#send{
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:#6895CC; 
    border:none;
    color:#fff;
}

#send:hover{
    background-color:#4E65C0;
}
body{ 
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size:11px; 
}

.messages{
    display:inline;
    width:250px; 
    height:638px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    border:solid #8CACDD;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px; 
    float:right; 
    border-width:0 0 1px 1px;
}
```

How do i move the messages column up on the right ? I have already included the `inline` element which removes any next line character before and after. what needs to be done to get it up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try giving `float:left` to `CSS` `#box`.

```
#box {
    border: 1px solid #6895CC;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #666666;
    float: left;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 50px 0 0 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure where exactly you imagine to be "up on the right".

I guessed you mean up on the right side within the form.

To do that you have to give your form elements a wrapper div, like:

```
<div id='Form'>
    <div id='box'>
        Name:<br>
        <input type='text' id='name' size='10'><br><br>
        Message:<br>
        <textarea id='message' size='15' ></textarea><br><br>
        <br>
        <div id='Send'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Send</div>
    </div>
    <div class='messages'>
        <div id='loader'>test</div>
        <ul class='update'></ul>
        <?php //include(messages.php) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and give the wrapper #Form element `position: relative;` and the .messages:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

look here if it what you want: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f3H9H/)